# Exclude linting in HTML

Tags: html, lint

Is there any way to make the TFS linter skip specific lines in an HTML file?

I have already tried `// @ts-ignore` , but it works on TypeScript/ JavaScript files (but not HTML).

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What is TFS linter? I have not know it before, could you please share some info/document about it? Or you just want to ignore some lines in html? If possible, please check https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/575

Comment: Are you using VScode?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT TFS: Team Foundation Server
Linter: a tool that checks if the code contains errors, bugs, etc
And I check your link, thanks :-)

Comment: @Ahmed Yes I do

Comment: I am not able to find anything about a product called "TFS Linter" or "Team Foundation Server Linter" when searching with Google. And when searching for "Linter" in Visual Studio Marketplace, I get just two results: VisualLinter and MultiLinter. Personally, I think you are mistaken about the product. If not, can you provide a hyperlink to the official website of "TFS Linter" please? (Such a reference is necessary for investigating your issue. Without it, it will be impossible to help you any further.)

Comment: TFS (Team Foundation Server) is a Microsoft product used for version control. Linter can be added to your coding tool (like VS Code) or version control tool. So by TFS linter I mean "linter which is used in TFS". In case you have not worked with the tool, you can skip the question. Thank you very much for your follow-up 
@BartHofland

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was just curious. I have used TFS before, both as a SCM tool and as a project management tool, but not for continuous integration. I will simply assume you want to use/integrate the linter for that purpose. Regarding linters, I have worked with both ESLint and TSLint. Even if I cannot help you any further with this, it still remains the question which linter is used by TFS in order to know how it can be configured. But if this is clear and obvious regarding TFS, then I will have no doubt that you will find a fitting solution soon. Sorry for the intrusion.